# Extend from React.Component class and connect to redux-store

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a class extending react.component. Another class extends from this class and connects to a redux-store.

```
import React from 'react'
class A extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){super(props); ...}
    ...
}

import React from 'react'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
@connect(store=>{...})
class B extends A{
    constructor(props){super(props); ...}
    ...
}

class C extend A{....}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work. Isn't it possible to connect a class to a store without explicitly extending the React.Component?

Error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function, not undefined
```

Comment: That _seems_ like it should work.  Can you give more info for what is or isn't happening?

Comment: You should avoid do inheritance between components, it is considered as good practice to only inherit from React.Component

Comment: For example: I have several list components, and all share the same behaviour (handlers etc.). Why shouldn't I export this functions into a component which I do extend and add only render functions. (I couldn't find a suitable design pattern)

Comment: The problem was offtipic, see my answear  please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imported class a via index.js. This didn't work, importing the file itself worked.

Answer (score 0):

As [Vincent Taing](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2871398/vincent-taing) said, it's not a good practice what you are trying to do. Instead use a HOC ( high order component ) to handle all of your logic (handlers, etc ), connect this component with your store and return your UI component with your handler.